Encrypt data before save into the database and Decrypt data after fetched from the database
In the database, I need to store data in an encrypted format. When retrieving the data, it should be automatically decrypted.
Consider the following class:
public class data
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Email { get; set; }

}

For the Password property, I want to ensure that during storage, the Email is saved in an encrypted format. When fetching the Email from the database, it should be returned in its decrypted form. Additionally, I need to handle this during migration, so the encryption and decryption behavior is predefined for the Password field.
